# How do I select nodes in a Drupal View that share a field value with the current logged in user?

Tags: drupal, view, pattern-matching, drupal-contextual-filters

It seems to me that I am missing something obvious.

I have a set of profiles authored by two separate groups of people with almost identical fields.

I want the current user to be able to run a view to find all the nodes of type Profile that have the same value of the field Primary Area of Interest as the logged in user. The logged in user and authors  of the other nodes will have different roles.

I have tried contextual filters and also using the views field views module to little effect. Any help appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Are you talking about Drupal 6 Profile module?

Comment: No sorry not to be clear its just a node with fields that describe a profile of the user - am working in drupal 7

Comment: Is there a reason why you keep this data on nodes instead adding fields on the user entity itself? How do connect the users with their profile nodes?